# Scipy optimize is just not dealing with the bound

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

I am trying to solve the following problem for many different values of K:

[image: \max_{p_2\sqrt{1-x_1} + (1-p_2)\sqrt{1-x_2}\geq K} p_1 \sqrt{x_1} + (1-p1) \sqrt{x_2}]

I am trying to use scipy optimize for greater generality (at some stage I would like to be able to change the functions).

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from scipy import optimize

n=10

p1 = 0.2
p2 = 0.3
orig = (0,0)
endw = (1,1)

def U1(x):
    return p1*(x[0])**0.5 + (1-p1)*(x[1])**0.5
def U2(x):
    return p2*(1-x[0])**0.5 + (1-p2)*(1-x[1])**0.5


itervals = np.linspace(endw, orig, n)
utvals = np.array([U2(vec) for vec in itervals])
parvals = np.zeros((2, len(utvals)))

for it in range(len(utvals)):
    def obj(x):
        return -U1(x)
    def constr(x):
        return -U2(x)+utvals[it]
    con = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constr}
    res = optimize.minimize(obj, itervals[it], method='SLSQP', constraints=con)
    parvals[:, it] = res['x']
    print(constr(parvals[:,it]), utvals[it])
```

However, when I check if the constrained is respected, I get negative values of `constr(parvals[:,it])` in the code above, and if I turn the constraint to

```
    def constr(x):
        return U2(x)-utvals[it]
```

I get positive values of `constr(parvals[:,it])`. How come?

I mean, my initial guess (contained in `itervals`) always returns 0 for the constraint. Therefore it is always possible to reach 0, why is it sometimes positive and sometimes negative?

Comment: As a side note, if `K >= 0`, `x1 = x2 = 1` seems optimal, and otherwise the problem seems unfeasible.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, you are right. I have corrected the problem. However you can see that still, it is not giving the right answer.

Comment: Always check the status of the results before looking at the levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varying K we find different solution pairs (x1, x2). Solving the maximization problem with Lagrange multiplier (imposing first order conditions) it is trivial to see that x2 must be a function of x1, i.e., this code gives the required relation:

```
Psi = (p1/p2*(1-p2)/(1-p1))**2
def realline(x1):
    return x1/(Psi+(1-Psi)*x1)
```

It can be easily seen that defining the constraint with the right sign, the solution coincides almost everywhere:

```
    def constr(x):
        return U2(x)-utvals[it]
    con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constr}
```